# Closing the a nonmodal dialog, makes the main window minimized

Tags: prism

Refer to this post https://prismlibrary.com/docs/wpf/dialog-service.html

1. Show a dialog via the following code

```
_dialogService.Show("MyDialog1", new DialogParameters($), r => { });
```

2. Move another Window of some other process over the Shell window(e.g MainFrame) of testing prism project. and "MainFrame" is hidden behind.
3. Click the the icon of MainFrame in the taskbar to bring "MyDialog1" and "MainFrame" to topmost, they become visible.
4. Close MyDialog1, then observe.
5. When close "MyDialog1", it is expected only to close "MyDialog1" and "MainFrame" should be stay shown normally, but observed that, the "MainFrame" is minimized unexpectedly.

Tested with Prism of 8.0.0.1850, this issue still exists since prism 6
How to improve the behavior of show nonmodal dialog?

Comment: Tested with a simple WPF(.NET Core) application, without "prism", this issue is also existing,
Not sure whether this is the WPF behavior or a WPF bug.

Comment: Found solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144004/wpf-app-loses-completely-focus-on-window-close